# How to filter all values in JSON object in dart / flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a search function where I search through all values in a JSON object without knowing the keys beforehand.

It goes something like this:

```
object.where((o) => o['name'].contains(searchString))
```

but notice that I have to specify the key 'name' to search through this part of the JSON. I want to be able to search through the entire JSON object and I don't know what the keys would be ahead of time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of output you expect?

Comment: 1. If you're going to answer your own question, you should post an *answer*, not edit it into your question. 2. You should recursively call `check` *only* if `value` is a `Map`.  Otherwise you'll end up with an uncaught exception if your `Map` contains values that aren't `String`s or `Map`s.

Comment: it ended up not working after all, I will need to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me is converting the entire object into a string representation and then doing the search. See below

```
bool check(dynamic o,String searchString) {
  if (jsonEncode(o).toString().contains(searchString)) {
  return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is only traversing all values:

```dart
bool check(o) {
  final values = o.values;
  for (final value in values) {
    if (value.contains(searchString) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

object.where((o) => check(o)).toList()
```

Comment: This is generally what I want but it doesnt work for JSON objects with an arbitrary structure (i.e. nested JSON)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search all the values from a json and then filter that satisfy your condition,

```
 final object={
    'name':'ashish',
    'address':{
      'city':'london',
      'zip': '2WW IXW'
    },
    'phone':'+432223',
    'brother':{
      'cousin':{
        'first_cousin':'ashish',
        'second_cousin':{
          'mother_side':'ashish',
          'father_side':'ashish'
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  
  List searchObject(Map<String, dynamic> obj, String searchString) {
      final listOfKeysThatMeetACondition=[];
    for (final key in obj.keys) {
    final value = obj[key];
      if(value is String ){
        if(value.contains(searchString)){


          listOfKeysThatMeetACondition.add(key);
          
        }
 
      }else if(value is Map<String,dynamic>){

     listOfKeysThatMeetACondition.addAll(searchObject(value, searchString));
        
        
      }
    

    
  }

  return listOfKeysThatMeetACondition;
}

 print(searchObject(object,'ashish'));
```

Here I am returning the list of keys from a nested json object that contains 'ashish' string.
I am not sure if this is what you were looking for but
I hope that helps somehow.
Will clarify any confusion if any. Thanks.

Comment: I think recursion is the key here. How can I adapt this for a list of objects? I want to return the objects in the list that meet the search string condition for the entire object

Comment: If you want to return a list of obj instead of list of keys(like I am doing here), you just need to add the obj (function argument) to the list and not key.That is           listOfKeysThatMeetACondition.add(obj) instead of       listOfKeysThatMeetACondition.add(key).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> objects = [
    {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 25},
    {'name': 'Jane Smith', 'age': 30},
    {'name': 'Alice Wonderland', 'age': 22},
  ];

  String searchString = 'Doe';

  // Filter the list of maps based on the 'name' containing the searchString
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredList = objects
      .where((map) => map['name'].toString().contains(searchString))
      .toList();

  // Print the filtered list
  print(filteredList);
}
```

but I'm not sure about the structure of your map